# помогите создать батник с рандомом

Tags: cmd

Кто может создать батник требовиние токие

-есть папка C:\test\in в ней 50 фаилов

-рандомно копировать с папки C:\test\in 3 фаила в папку  C:\test\out

Answer (score 0):

Мне видится что-то такое (комментарии потрите - в `.bat` они иначе пишутся):

```
@echo off
chcp 855
SETLOCAL EnableDelayedExpansion

set sourceFolder=C:\Folder1 // "папка, откуда будем копировать"
set destFolder=C:\Folder2   // "папка, куда будем копировать"
set counter=0
set filesToCopy=3           // "на самом деле, количество скидываемых зависит от последнего цикла, но тут тоже нужно указать"
set /a filesInFolder=50+1   // "количество файлов + 1"

for /L %%i in (1,1,%filesToCopy%) do (set /a rndm=!filesInFolder!*!random!/32768>nul
    if !rndm! EQU 0 (set /a rndm+=1)  // "не надо нам копировать 0 файлов..."
    set file%%i=!rndm!)

cd %sourceFolder%
for %%j in (*) do (set /a counter=!counter!+1>nul
    if !counter! EQU %file1% (xcopy "%%j" "%destFolder%" /d /g /r /k /y)
    if !counter! EQU %file2% (xcopy "%%j" "%destFolder%" /d /g /r /k /y)
    if !counter! EQU %file3% (xcopy "%%j" "%destFolder%" /d /g /r /k /y)
    // "и вот тут будут добавляться строки для file4, file5 и т.д."

)

pause
```

Недостаток `.bat` в том, что, если надо будет больше файлов передавать, то в идеале либо в последний цикл `for` впихивать еще один, который просто будет перебирать цифры, либо добавлять еще больше строк. Все потому что он `OR` не знает. :(

Поэтому история с рандомом выглядит жутко костыльной.)

Comment: может тогда в powershell можно чтото придумать?

Comment: @user514720 да можно, наверное. 
но этот я потестил, у меня все выполняется. может, кто-то что-то еще предложит. я пока вижу только вариант через счетчик.